# How to calculate the convolution of a function with itself multiple times in Wolfram?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

Excuse me I am new to Wolfram. I have seen people asking questions about how to do convolution of a function with itself in Wolfram. However, I wonder how to do it multiple times in a loop. That is to say I want to do f20* i.e. f*f*f*f*....f totaling 20 f. How to implement it?

Here is my thinking. Of course do not work....

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{0.1`, x >= 0 && x <= 10}, {0, x < 0}, {0, x > 10}}];
g = f;
n = 19;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, g = Convolve[f[x], g, x, y]]; Plot[
   g[x], {x, -10, n*10 + 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Could anybody help me?

My new code after revising agentp's code

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{0.1, x >= 0 && x <= 10}, {0, x < 0}, {0,x > 10}}];
n = 19;
res = NestList[Convolve[#, f[x], x, y] /. y -> x &, f[x], n]; 
Plot[res, {x, -10, (n + 1)*10 + 10}, PlotRange -> All,PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[My buggy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuVGc.jpg)

Comment: n should be 19....

Comment: Is there a method to overcome the machine precision when n is large = 19?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this?

```
 Nest[ Convolve[#, f[x], x, y] /. y -> x  &, f[x] , 3]
```

[image]

If that's not right maybe show what you get by hand for n=2 or 3.

```
res = NestList[ Convolve[#, f[x], x, y] /. y -> x  &, f[x] , 10];
Plot[res, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

this gets very slow with n, I don't have the patience to run it out to 20.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: I get a bug when running with n = 20.... When n = 20 The graph gets weird.

Comment: You are probably running into precision issues.  Try making the `0.1` exact `1/10` so you get exact rational coefficients for the polynomials. (Plot still works at machine precision so you may still have issues)

Comment: It doesn't help. And I found if i use n = 19 instead of n = 20. The last one just get weird.

Comment: Is there a method to overcome the machine precision when n is large = 19?

Comment: give `Plot` the options `WorkingPrecision->20` and `Exclusions->None`. ( and the input float value `0.1` must be either exact `1/10` or extended precision, ``0.1`20`` )

Comment: ...I wrote last comment after it worked for me with `1/10`.  ``0.1`20`` does *not* work, you may need to start with even higher precision.

Comment: Thanks. 1/10 works for me too. But 1.0/10.0 and 0.1`20 or 30 does not work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is nearly working. You just have to

1. make sure to copy `f` by value before entering the loop, because otherwise you face infinite recursion.
2. Assign the result of `Convolve` to a function which takes a parameter.

This is the code with the mentioned changes:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{0.1, x >= 0 && x <= 10}, {0, x < 0}, {0, x > 10}}];
g[x_] = f[x];
n = 20;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, g[y_] = Convolve[f[x], g[x], x, y]];
Plot[g[x], {x, -10, n*10 + 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Edit: While this works, agentp's answer is more consise and i suspect also faster.